# Possible to override $fastcgi_script_name in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Sometimes you have to override the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` used for certain requests in Nginx. But if `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` is part of an include file such as fastcgi.conf that's included in your Nginx configuration in many places, it gets ugly to pull `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` out of there and sprinkle it into your main configuration file only in order to override it in one place.

Usually `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` has the value `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` so overriding `$fastcgi_script_name` would be the perfect solution. But the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#variables) says that is an embedded variable, so is there no way to override it?

This would be good if it worked but it does not:

```
location /example {
  root = /files/example_files;
  fastcgi_script_name = special.php;
  include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Nor this:

```
location /example {
  root = /files/example_files;
  set $fastcgi_script_name special.php;
  include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Error message is:

> the duplicate "fastcgi_script_name" variable

Comment: why not simply rewrite the request so that there is no variable munging required?

Comment: Trying to avoid using rewrites on principle (they are not efficient, a holdover from the Apache way of thinking)

Comment: It is the tool to do what you're trying to do - use the right tool.

Comment: There's more than one way to do most things and if you must insist, I must retort that setting fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME is a better tool than what you suggest. No rewrite engine required. My question follows on that trying to see about feasibility of working out cleaner configuration. Please address my actual question, as it may also be of more general use. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Ask how to achieve _an objective_; you currently have an [X/Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it's not productive to pursue the solution you've chosen, which is flawed (and no, "override $fastcgi_script_name" is not an objective). Also `they are not efficient` - Feel free to demonstrate that.

Comment: The problem is that if you use rewrite rules you change the other variables passed to the FastCGI script as well, so that the script thinks it is executing from a different path (and thus the URLs it generates are wrong.)  Changing `$fastcgi_script_name` will allow you to launch the script from a different path without that different internal path leaking back to the browser.